# How to get XPath node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to get the XPath node using XSLT. I need to check if a particular node exists within a block of xml. The only way i klnow how to do it is using the XPath node. Let me know if you know of another way to check if a certain node exists within a block of XML using XSLT.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. All access to the source document from an XSLT stylesheet uses XPath expressions, so the simple answer is that there isn't another way (other than XPath). Please try to explain your problem more clearly: what's the input you're starting with, and what's the output you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, XPath is the way.

Assuming you're in an XSLT template and you want to check for the existence of a child element "TestElement", you could do something like:

```
<xsl:if test="TestElement">
    <!-- some-code -->
</xsl:if>
```

Simply specifying the element/node name in a test checks for the existence of that element/node.

---

Sounds like I completely misunderstood the question. If you want to generate an "absolute" XPath expression for an given node in a given document from within XSLT, [there's a lovely succinct solution described here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200207/post41700.html).

Comment: Is there a way to get the xpath node from the current() function

Comment: OK, I think I thoroughly misunderstood your question: are you asking for a way to get an XPath expression that would evaluate to a given node, from the document root presumably, and have that expression generated/derived from within an XSLT document?

Comment: I need to get the xpath node so I can use it in an 'if' statement. I need to check and see if the current node exists in a block of xml

Comment: I think we need more detail here. 1) You're writing an XSLT 2) Within that XSLT, you have templates that match portions of a source Xml document 3) at some point in that XSLT code, you want to get a) an xpath expression representing the current node, b) something else?? At the moment it sounds like you want to check whether the current node exists - of course it exists, otherwise it couldn't be the current node! :) Can yu provide a code sample illustrating the context where you are trying to do something?